# Pragmatically How to add Default Error Pages for IIS website Using C#?

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7

I know how to add error pages for IIS website using asp.net in Web.config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And we can add manually in IIS.

But i want to add error pages based on Website Name.

For Example..

> Website name: "Foo1"
>
> Error Page Should be:  \Foo1\err.html

How to add Error Pages from C# using console or WinForms.
Please help me

Comment: What do you mean by "using console or WinForms"? Do you want to alter the web.config files of various sites by code?

Comment: No @Fabiano,. I want to add Error Page using System.Web.Administation dll. Not by using web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your web.config file in your websites, assuming the application pool it is running under has the correct permissions to modify it.

This can be done using the [WebConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Assuming you are just wanting to modify the DefaultRedirect, you should be able to use code like below:

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var section = (CustomErrorsSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");
if(section != null)
{
    section.DefaultRedirect = "yourpage.htm";
    configuration.Save();
}
```

EDIT:  If you are wanting to do this via Microsoft.Web.Administration, then the following code should allow you to access the web configuration for a particular website, and set the customErrors defaultRedirect to a new value:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    Configuration configuration = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("your website name");

    ConfigurationSection customErrorsSection = configuration.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");
    customErrorsSection.SetAttributeValue("defaultRedirect", "/your error page.htm");
    serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Can we able to write error pages like the below snippet using System.Web.Administration..Like  iisManager.Sites["foo"].ErrorPage....

Comment: @Prashee are you wanting to configure the ASP customErrors, or the IIS errors?  Also, are you wanting to do this from the website itself, or from another application?

Comment: Yes, From Console Application I want to configure IIS Errors to set the Default Error Page.

Comment: @Prashee check the edited answer to see if this helps you further.  If it is not the customError pages you want to edit, can access the Error pages through `configuration.GetSection("system.web/httpErrors")` and setting the `defaultPath` attribute

Comment: Thanks for your help.